# How to set default Wifi to connect to?

Tags: wireless, settings, default

I logged onto my neighbors wifi one time like a year ago and every single time I close my laptop it will log out of my wifi and try to log-in to my neighbors even though I barely get any signal from theirs. Is it possible to set the default wifi connection? I'm running 14.10 atm.

Thank you.